# Why can't I use fixed and setprecision() with +operator for strings instead of <<operator for cout

Tags: c++, string, operator-keyword, fixed, iomanip

Why can't I use "fixed" and "setprecision()" with the +operator to format it into a string and that I only can use it only with the less-than-less-than-operator to format it for cout. What are other ways I can implement this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 157.2734;
    cout << "This number is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << a << "." << endl;
    string line = "This number is " + fixed + setprecision(1) + a + "." + "\n"; // This doesn't work this way! Why!?!?!?
    cout << line;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision()` are manipulators for streams. You can instead format the string using a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: It's called [stream insertion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) `<<`, not _less-than-less-than-operator_.

Comment: In addition to @Ron Originally, `<<` and `>>` are bit-shift-operators. They have been "abused" for streams (by overloading).

Comment: @Ron, actually it is shift operator.

Comment: It's a fair question insofar that it does look inconsistent but, under the hood, your two statements are doing very different things. The stream method overloads the `<<` operator, the string overloads `+` for concatenation.

Comment: Strings don't do formatting. Streams do. Streams don't do element access. Strings do. They're fundamentally different things, and the things they do are appropriate to their jobs.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I use "fixed" and "setprecision()" with the +operator to format it into a string?

Have a closer look at [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

The complete signature of `std::fixed`:

```
std::ios_base& fixed(std::ios_base& str);
```

So, it is designed to work with streams exclusively.

In the case of `std::setprecision()`, it's a bit tricky:

```
/*unspecified*/ setprecision( int n );
```

However:

> Returns an object of unspecified type such that if str is the name of an output stream of type std::basic_ostream or an input stream of type std::basic_istream, then the expression str << setprecision(n) or str >> setprecision(n) behaves as if the following code was executed:

```
  str.precision(n);
```

So, it might have worked if there were a `std::string::precision()` method but there isn't one.

---

> What are other ways I can implement this?

The possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 157.2734;
    cout << "This number is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << a << "." << endl;
    ostringstream fmtStr;
    fmtStr << "This number is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << a << ".\n";
    string line = fmtStr.str();
    cout << line;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This number is 157.3.
This number is 157.3.
```

[**Life demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/rfT9UA)

Comment: Update: Forgot the `#include <sstream>`. In ideone (gcc) it worked without but _with_ is correct.